# Iniciando com .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, url, mod-rewrite

Olá;
Estou tentando criar URLs amigáveis para um site, só que não estou obtendo êxito em vários exemplos que testei pela internet. Creio que meu problema esteja na maneira como devo redirecionar a estrutura do meu site, possuo a página empresa.php que fica dentro de outras subpastas, tendo esse caminho: `website/pageswebsite/empresa.php`.
Estou tentando que a URL possa ser acionada apenas através de: `www.site.com/empresa` da seguinte maneira:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^empresa/?$ website/pageswebsite/empresa.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Já tentei de diversas formas, mas não obtive êxito, peço ajuda do fórum até por que não conhecia muito sobre `.htaccess`, agora que estou começando a trabalhar com o mesmo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica se o mod_rewrite do apache esta ativado. Pra isso crie um arquivo info.php na raiz da aplicacao e nele coloque:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

entao va ate o browser e chame a url pra esse arquivoe nele verifique se o mod_rewrite esta ativado. Se nao tiver vc pode executar o comando:

```
a2enmode rewrite
```

e em seguida reinicar o apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```